# How to override the rake input prompt for automation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rake, rake-task

I have been trying `rake app:update:bin[a]`, `rake app:update:bin\[a\]`, and others. I'd really like to figure this out if it can be.

```
$ bundle exec rake app:update:bin
       exist  bin
    conflict  bin/rails
Overwrite /home/me/coinship/bin/rails? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm]
```